# Monitor clipboard from WinService

Tags: c#, c++, windows-services, clipboard

How to setup a clipboard monitor in Windows 7. The main thing that we would like to setup the monitor from the windows service and **not** usual application.

Comment: That doesn't make sense.  The clipboard is per-user; services are not.

Comment: Well, it does make sense -- a service might want to enumerate all logged in users and se what's in their clipboards.

Comment: please elaborate - what is the goal you want to achieve exactly ? what have you tried ? what is not working ? Why a Windows Service (since clipboard is per "session/user") ?

Comment: -1, seriously?  Just because you don't understand *why* he wants to do it??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is most likely impossible because servie will be running on a different WindowStation that the interactively logged in user.  Perhaps, you could try opening the user WinStation and attaching to it, but I'm not sure whether this is possible from a service -- Microsoft has worked hard on isolating window stations from each other.

If I'm right and [OpenWindowStation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684339%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) doesn't work for you due to security constraints, you will have to run an interactive agent process for each logged in user and have it communicate to the service instance using some kind of IPC.

Comment: Well, we would like to monitor all clipboards of logged users for changes.

Comment: I'm not arguing with you.  I think this is a valid question, but it might not be possible.

Comment: everything is possible... sometimes you need some trickery (like injecting code somewhere or writing a kernel-mode device driver) but you get there eventually... whether it makes sense/is worth the hassle/is "a production-quality solution" that's a rather different discussion though

Comment: @Yahia of course.  When I say "impossible" I mean "unreasonably hackish".